# Are there any Ajax(Prototype or JQuery Plugin) sample for stackoverflow-like voting?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins, prototypejs

any good ajax samples for implementing voting similar to the up and down buttons of stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

You create a page for voting like yoursite.com/vote?postid=1234&direction=up that saves the vote in the database. Then you create buttons or links for voting and perform an Ajax request when the user clicks the link:

jquery:

```
$.post("vote", { postid: the_id, direction: "up" })
```

Comment: any idea how to do that in GSP pages?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never used GSP (I didn't even know it existed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one: http://www.technabled.com/2011/02/pulse-lite-reddit-ajax-up-down-voting.html
Disclosure: I am the developer.