# How can I implement a voting system (UP/DOWN) or (THUMP UP/DOWN) like StackOverFlow in .NET?

Tags: .net, ajax, silverlight, vote, vote-up-buttons

How can I implement a voting system (UP/DOWN) or (THUMP UP/DOWN) like StackOverFlow in .NET ? I found PHP codes but I want something that works in .NET environment. I don't care about security issues like multi votes and such restrictions at this stage.

Comment: are you looking for a silverlight implementation? you have it marked in your tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create stackoverflow's post voting like jquery/ajax function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659904/how-to-create-stackoverflows-post-voting-like-jquery-ajax-function)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the framework as it has been published, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [simple voting application similar to stackoverflow.com](http://angularcode.com/voting-system-similar-to-stackoverflow-using-angularjs-php-and-mysql/) using angularjs, php and mysql with code to download.

You just need to change the 2 php files into ASP.NET files which gets and updates the voteCount.

Everthing else will be intact. Creating the voting app using AngularJS is much easier and flexible.