# Create Ajax voting system

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 3 and jquery.

I want to implement a comments system on my site with the ability to up vote and down vote comments. I want the voting to be done via Ajax (without redirect). It should update the votecount and prevent further voting on that comment.

Can someone explain how I can do this. What jquery functions should I call and how to use them?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create stackoverflow's post voting like jquery/ajax function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659904/how-to-create-stackoverflows-post-voting-like-jquery-ajax-function)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad. You might use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to send an AJAX request to a controller action which would update the vote count into the database given a question id:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("VoteUp") %>',
    data: { questionId: 1234 },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('thanks for upvoting this question');
    }
});
```

Obviously the controller action should check if the currently logged in user hasn't already upvoted this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a generic handler (.ashx) to deal with the database and call it by using the ajax call.
For example:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com/webservices")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class UpVote : IHttpHandler
{  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    { 
       // Create this method to deal with your database
       MakeUpVote(context.Request["commentID"].tostring());   // Comment ID is the input
} }
```

Now Call the Method by Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            url: "UpVote.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ "commentID": commentID }),
            success: function(result) {
 alert ("You have upvoted");}
                    });
```

Comment: You can check the currently logged in user status like Upvoted or not in the .ASHX files too.

Comment: Three are much better ways of creating an ajax web service in ASP.NET MVC.  A generic handler should not be used.